# Unable to retrieve data from Firebase Database. ref.child("").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent being unresponsive

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve a list of posts from my firebase database, but it is not working. The specific piece of code that I am having trouble with is the `line ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent`. When I debug the application, it just skips over this line and the app jumps to `ref.removeAllObservers()`. Am I calling the correct functions to retrieve from my database? The tutorial I am using is from Swift3 so it may be outdated.

I have tried calling observe instead of observeSingleEvent, but that had the same outcome.

Here is my fetchPosts function:

```
func fetchPosts(){
        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
            let users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

            for (_,value) in users {
                if let uid = value["uid"] as? String{
                    if uid == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                        if let followingUsers = value["following"] as? [String: String]{
                            for(_, user) in followingUsers {
                                self.following.append(user)
                            }
                        }
                        self.following.append(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)

                        ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

                            let postsSnap = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

                            for(_, post) in postsSnap {
                                if let userID = post["userID"] as? String{
                                    for each in self.following{
                                        if each == userID{
                                            let posst = Post()
                                            if let author = post["author"] as? String, let likes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String{

                                                posst.author = author
                                                posst.likes = likes
                                                posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                                                posst.postID = postID
                                                posst.userID = userID

                                                self.posts.append(posst)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    self.collectionview.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }

        })
         ref.removeAllObservers()
    }
```

I hope to fill a collection view with post information from my Firebase database. There are no error messages.